# UI push notification not present in Android Device - Xamarin Plugin.FirebasePushNotification

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Plugin.FirebasePushNotifications in xamarin to receive push notification. When I send the notify message, it can run inside **CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived** but not display the notification. Can you help me how to get the notification display in android device
Here is my MainApplication.cs code

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        //CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);

        //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //Change for your default notification channel id here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

            //Change for your default notification channel name here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
        }


        //If debug you should reset the token each time.
        //if DEBUG
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, new DefaultPushNotificationHandler(), true);
        //else
          FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
        //endif

        //Handle notification when app is closed here
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {

        };


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you added google-services.json to Android project?

Comment: I've already added it, but like it appear push notification in the background but not popping up on the screen like Gmail

Comment: So notifications are appearing , but it only appears in the notification tray. Is that your problem?

Comment: You want it to popup out the top display like whatsapp. Is that your requirement?

Comment: @NguyễnMinhChí Hi , do you have a check with this sample and whether occurs this phenomenon ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/firebase-fcmnotifications

Comment: Spending hours to search, I figured out that no way to make it appear like that (heads up) when using firebase, I searched it depends on PRIORITY of notification but when I changed it, nothing happen. It can received on background but not display heads up

Comment: @NguyễnMinhChí Glad found the solution ! You can update this in answer then other people will see the solution :-)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I just realized that the problem can not be solved completely =))) so we just do it in normal way